# Update Gridview on treeview node checked

Tags: asp.net

I need to update or filter the records in gridview, when I check a node in treeview **without postback.**
I tried placing the gridview in update panel and registered ASYNCPOSTBACKTRIGGER for treeviews NODECHECKCHANGED event, but still the postback occurs.

How can I solve this or any other approach? please help

Answer (score 0):

Change autopostback event to false, select trigger for update panel. IF it wont work, use another update panel for treeview.